# Junit Test for algorithm

Tags: java, junit

I try to solve this problem:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit

This is the code that I wrote:

```
public class Hello {
        static int counter = 0;
        public static int persistence(long n) {
        int digits = digit_count(n);
        if (digits <= 1) {
          return 0;
        }
        persistence(product(n));
        counter++;
        return counter;
        }
      public static int product(long n) {
      int productValue = 1;
        while (n != 0) {
          productValue *= n % 10;
            n /= 10;
         }
        return productValue;
      }

      public static int digit_count(long n) {
        int count = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
          n /= 10;
          count++;
        }
        return count;
      }
```

and JUnit test:

```
assertEquals(3, Hello.persistence(39));
assertEquals(0, Hello.persistence(4));
assertEquals(2, Hello.persistence(25));
assertEquals(4, Hello.persistence(999));
```

the tests fails for 25 and 999, but if I try to call Hello.persistence(25) and Hello.persistence(999) in *main* method I got the needed values.
Please, explain how this is possible?

Comment: No, first two asserts runs well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reverting the state of `counter` to 0 between invocations:

```
Hello.persistence(39);
//counter is now equal to 3, furter invocations will add "3" to the result
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you very much. I must get rid of static variable

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at your outcomes and asking "Why am I not getting what I think I should be getting?". Using a debugger you would find your counter isn't being reset before you call `persistance` from the outside. `Hello.persistance(39)` sets the counter to 3 and then `Hello.persistance(4)` returns a hard coded value of 0.

Create a new class for each of your test cases and you'll be fine.